# How to print an array in comma separated string in angular html

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

I have to display a  parse an array inside a json in HTML:

```
 <p class="personaType">{{cardData.names}}</p>
```

where names is

```
names: Array(5) 0:"Person" 1:"Artist" 2:"Performing Artist" 3:"Production Artist" 4:"Visual Artist" 5:"Intermedia Artist"
```

**I want to display names as:**

> Person, Artist, Performing Artist, Production Artist

**Right now it is displaying as (without space):**

> Person,Artist,Performing Artist,Production Artist

Is there any inbuilt pipe available in angular which can be used to display such data?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) (notice the white space after the comma)

```
<p class="personaType">{{cardData.names.join(', ')}}</p>
```

This will print all the elements in the array, separated by a comma and a white space.

Comment: Glad it helped. Note that this is not specific to Angular, is just a standard JS array method

Comment: Yes I can understand that. but it is not a hack? right? it is a right way to do it?

Comment: @Simer it's definitely not a hack

Comment: Hey, I tried it and got:  ERROR TypeError: _v.parent.context.$implicit.se.join is not a function

Comment: You've probably calling`join` on something that's not an array

Comment: It's not a hack, but see the answer below for how you should do it in angular to be more performant.

Comment: This answer an Angular "bad practice" due to running a function directly inside the template html and a pipe should be used instead. See the answer below

Comment: This is perfectly working. But is there a solution to print only on the element of the array? For example, if in the array names I have many objects like name:[ {firstname: "aaa", Lastname:"bbb"}, {firstname: "ccc", Lastname:"ddd"} ]
Is there a way to display only aaa, ccc using interpolation?

Comment: This answer is wrong, because Angular's change-detection will always rerun the `.join()`-method. A pipe works a little bit different and don't waste CPU time.

Answer (score 57):

To minimize the load on your application, you might also consider creating a pipe.

The transform function would look like this:

```js
@Pipe({
  name: 'join'
})
export class JoinPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(input:Array<any>, sep = ','): string {
    return input.join(sep);
  }
}
```

It could look something like this, as far as usage:

```html
<p>{{ cardData.names|join:', ' }}</p>
```

Comment: Should be the accepted answer to be honest, though the example could be more fleshed out.

Comment: @crush I put the entire pipe in there. Let me know if you had something else in mind.

Comment: Good answer! I would also add `pure: true`

Comment: @YosvelQuintero You could do that. According to the documentation, [they are pure by default](https://angular.io/api/core/Pipe#pipe). That said, sometimes it is better to be more explicit, depending on the needs of the codebase.